# Как эмулировать ввод нескольких значений с консоли?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Необходимо эмулировать ввод с консоли, но не одного значения, а нескольких. Для одного значения применялась следующая практика:

```
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("...".getBytes()));
System.setIn(System.in);
```

Как сделать для нескольких значений, если это возможно?

Comment: а если значения переводом строки разделять, типа "значение1\nзначение2"?

Comment: Пробовал так делать. Не получается

Comment: Через разделитель не подойдет? С последующей разбивкой при обработке?

Comment: Я вот не могу только понять. Как потом можно передавать значения в консоли по порядку.